# Setting a defined random order for an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random, shuffle

I have an array of over 1000s keys in PHP which I want to randomize. I am currently using shuffle to do this, however I want the shuffled order to be the same everytime. So, random but always in the same random order everytime the script is ran.

It's a client request :). Randomize, but keep it the same random order everytime.

Comment: Call it psudo random then. He descibes exactly what he needs and your comment is pointless

Comment: Ask which random he likes most and then change seed number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `srand(int seed)` first, with a constant. e.g. `srand(123)`.